# Which controls are supported in Coded UI in c# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I am working on c# winforms. And using Coded UI for automation testing. Can any one tell which controls are supported and which controls are not supported in c# winform for Coded UI?

Comment: I would imagine all of them. All controls derive from a base class Control. Are you experiencing a problem?

Comment: @Crowcoder .Yeah, i am facing issue with ribbonbutton control. I have also posted query on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368757/system-windows-forms-ribbon-controls-in-codedui), here i am unable to find the ribbonbutton in my ribbon in Coded UI used in c# winform

Comment: You can always create your own.  I have created a bunch myself for HTML but the concept would be similar.  Here are some examples https://github.com/spelltwister/CodedUIFluentExtensions/tree/master/CodedUIExtensions/CaptainPav.Testing.UI.CodedUI/Html/AdditionalControls